# How can i move actor's bounding box center in relative location in Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: c++, trigonometry, unreal-5, bounding-boxes

This is my situation. I need align the center of the object (it's box) and the center of the scene component. I have only center of the box TVector type or FVector. How can i do it?

````
FBox Box;

//some shity code

auto Center = Box.GetCenter();

SomeActor->AttachToComponent(SomeUSceneComponent, SomeAttachmentRules)
SomeActor->SetRelativeLocation(??????)

```
````